# Paperclip/Remotipart AJAX Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip and Remotipart to handle some AJAX file uploads (uploads and display images with AJAX).

I'm using Rails 3.2.11

The problem is, while the record is being created, the attachment fields are all nil and no image actually gets uploaded. Here is the small form:

```
<%= form_tag("/portfolios/upload_port_img", method: "post", :html => { :multipart => true }, remote: true, :class=>'fileup') do |t| %>
        <% file_field_tag(:attachment) %>       
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form, I get this response:

```
Processing by PortfoliosController#upload_port_img as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+/pPeTYu9filNt5M2+BNYIc9+8kzLyo4pvCB6oMC0U0=", "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01", "attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000003417488 @original_filename="6jPQg1l.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment\"; filename=\"6jPQg1l.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131123-10843-h6wdmc>>}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (4.3ms)  INSERT INTO "portfolio_files" ("attachment_content_type", "attachment_file_name", "attachment_file_size", "attachment_updated_at", "created_at", "description", "portfolio_id", "position", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["attachment_content_type", nil], ["attachment_file_name", nil], ["attachment_file_size", nil], ["attachment_updated_at", nil], ["created_at", Sat, 23 Nov 2013 23:41:27 UTC +00:00], ["description", nil], ["portfolio_id", nil], ["position", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 23 Nov 2013 23:41:27 UTC +00:00]]
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
   (9.4ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered portfolios/upload_port_img.js.erb (31.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 69.6ms | ActiveRecord: 14.1ms)
```

Yet still, no image is uploaded. Any idea why this may be?